# Can't retreive input from html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Html contains:

```
<span class="AIvhS _3MboC _2YsGM _22FXo ywmsL" data-reactid=".n.6.1:0.1:3">
    <span class="_3hurI" data-reactid=".n.6.1:0.1:3.0">
        <input class="_2ixY2 _1qXYA" value="" data-reactid=".n.6.1:0.1:3.0.1" autocomplete="off">
    </span><span class="_1Q8WE" data-reactid=".n.6.1:0.1:3.2">*</span>
</span>
```

I want to set `input` value. What I am doing at first is retreive `input` object reference by this:

`document.getElementsByClassName("_2ixY2 _1qXYA");`

Unfortunelly for some reason this is returning `undefinded` in response. Why does that happen?

Comment: Those class names are not very human friendly.  How the heck do you remember what they do?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

[.getElementsByClassName("")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array of elements with that class name. use `document.getElementsByClassName("_2ixY2 _1qXYA")[0]` to get the first one and use `.value` to set its value

Comment: It doesn't return array of elements. It returns `undefinded`.

Comment: so you used document.getElementsByClassName("_2ixY2 _1qXYA") and logged what it returned and it says "undefined"?

Comment: When are you calling the document.getElementsByClassName @dafie ? Are you sure your element exist at this moment ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.querySelector('input[class="_2ixY2 _1qXYA"]');
```

But I would like to just point out that it isn't recommended to query the DOM directly in react because it will cause problems with the React's Virtual DOM

Comment: document.querySelector("input[class='_2ixY2 _1qXYA']"); would be cleaner :)

Comment: So what would be recommended to do?

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns array of all elements that contains the givven class so you can run your code like that

```
var input_element = document.getElementsByClassName("_2ixY2 _1qXYA")[0];
input_element.value = 'hiii';
```

and here is a working [snnipet](https://jsfiddle.net/mohammad408/wbL4ran5/6/)